# mysqladmin generates "error" messages

Tags: mysql, logrotate, mariadb

Some time ago I installed NGINX, php7, mariaDB and Wordpress on my Raspberry Pi running Raspbian.

I created a Wordpress database - which is working.

Recently I installed `ssmtp` and `mailutils` on my system to send mail.

Now I get a daily email with the following error

```
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate:
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
error: error running shared postrotate script for '/var/log/mysql/mysql.log /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log /var/log/mysql/error.log '
run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/logrotate exited with return code 1
```

This mildly annoying. There is no file `/var/log/mysql/mysql.log`

The root user of mysql does have a password.

What can I do to suppress the error messages?

EDIT

---

`/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` calls `/etc/logrotate.conf`

which contains

```
# rotate log files weekly
weekly
…
# packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d
```

which includes

`/etc/logrotate.d/mysql-server`

```
# - I put everything in one block and added sharedscripts, so that mysql gets
#   flush-logs'd only once.
#   Else the binary logs would automatically increase by n times every day.
# - The error log is obsolete, messages go to syslog now.
/var/log/mysql/mysql.log /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log /var/log/mysql/error.log {
    daily
    rotate 7
    missingok
    create 640 mysql adm
    compress
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
          test -x /usr/bin/mysqladmin || exit 0
          if [ -f `my_print_defaults --mysqld | grep -m 1 -oP "pid-file=\K.+$"` ]; then
            # If this fails, check debian.conf!
            mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf --local flush-error-log \
              flush-engine-log flush-general-log flush-slow-log
          fi
    endscript
}
```

`/etc/mysql/debian.cnf` contains

```
# Automatically generated for Debian scripts. DO NOT TOUCH!
[client]
host     = localhost
user     = root
password = 
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[mysql_upgrade]
host     = localhost
user     = root
password = 
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
basedir  = /usr
```

Comment: Have you checked the `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` file to see what the cron job is doing?

Answer (score 0):

- go to your mysql/mariadb client and assure that *debian-sys-maint* user with empty password is already present in *user* table of *mysql* database
- default `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf` should contain **debian-sys-maint** as *user* instead of **root**

```
# Automatically generated for Debian scripts. DO NOT TOUCH!
[client]
host     = localhost
user     = debian-sys-maint
password =
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[mysql_upgrade]
host     = localhost
user     = debian-sys-maint
password =
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
basedir  = /usr
```